# Как брать значение из Entry в Xamarin xaml?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Synlab.LoginForm">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="20"
                         VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Entry Placeholder="Login"
                       Text="{Binding Login}"
                   x:Name="Login"/>
            <Entry Placeholder="Password"
                       Text="{Binding Password}"
                       IsPassword="true"
                   x:Name="Password"/>
            <Button Text="Login" TextColor="White"
                        BackgroundColor="#DCDDE0"
                        Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"
                        Clicked="LogIn"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Нужно взять значения из Login и Password полей

```
 string login = Login.Text;
```

Но поля логина и пароля компилятор не распознает.

Answer (score 0):

Решил добавлением двух событий и их обработкой.

```
            <Entry x:Name="Login" 
            Placeholder="Login"
                   Text="{Binding Login}"
                Completed="Login_Completed"
                PropertyChanged="Login_Completed"
               />

        <Entry x:Name="Password" 
            Placeholder="Password"
                   Text="{Binding Password}"
                   IsPassword="true"
                Completed="Password_Completed"
                PropertyChanged="Password_Completed"
               />
```

А вот получение значений.

```
        void Login_Completed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        login = ((Entry)sender).Text;
    }


    void Password_Completed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        password = ((Entry)sender).Text;
    }
```